# How to assign List.count to a variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to summate the lengths of two lists in C# Unity, but have been unsuccessful. The integer variables "oneCount" and "twoCount" return 0 every time, even after increasing the list size. I'm sure there's an easy solution, but I'm completely stuck.

My code looks like the following:

```
public class list : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<int> oneList = new List<int>();
    List<int> twoList = new List<int>();

    int oneCount;
    int twoCount;

    void Start()
    {

        oneCount = oneList.Count;
        twoCount = twoList.Count;

    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {

            oneList.Add(1);

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {

            twoList.Add(1);

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {

            Final();

        }

    void Final()
    {

        Debug.Log(oneCount + twoCount);

    }
```

Comment: You are not updating them anywhere, and only checking the count at the start of the program, where the lists are empty

Comment: Sorry about the newbie question, but how would I go about updating them?

Comment: You should check the count in the `Update` method

Comment: Why not just use oneList.Count+twoList.Count everywhere? Why have a variable, that you have to update, track a list property(that updates automatically)?

Comment: `int` is a value type, so when you do `oneCount = oneList.Count;` it makes a copy of the value of `oneList.Count` and stores it into oneCount. After that, the values are totally independent of each other (at least until you write more code to update them). Just use `oneList.Count` when you need the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.Count` gives you the value at the time of that call.

```
var list = new List<int>();
var c1 = list.Count; // c1 is 0
list.Add(1); 
var c2 = list.Count; // c2 = 1, and c1 is still 0
```

It seems that in your example you don't need the `oneCount` and `twoCount` variables:

```
void Final()
{
   Debug.Log(oneList.Count + twoList.Count);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify you finall method as below it will work

```
void Final()
{
   Start(); // since assignment you have done in this method
    Debug.Log(oneCount + twoCount);

}
```